# Select SQL Query with Alias and Join

Tags: sql, database, wordpress, group-by

I'm working on a query for 2 days now, but I don't know how to make it.

Basically I'm doing a Query using multiple join:

My Query :

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_title, wp_posts.post_content, wp_posts.post_type,     
wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy, wp_terms.name
FROM wp_term_relationships, wp_term_taxonomy, wp_terms, wp_posts
WHERE wp_term_relationships.object_id =80
AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = wp_terms.term_id
AND wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_posts.ID
```

That's what she display (on the top), and what I wanna display (bottom)

http://tinyurl.com/cnjmuxs

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe someone else has a cleaner way to do this, but the following should work:

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_title, wp_posts.post_content, wp_posts.post_type, 
    MAX(
        CASE WHEN wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'reference' THEN wp_terms.name ELSE '' END 
    ) AS reference,
    MAX(
        CASE WHEN wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'chinesename' THEN wp_terms.name ELSE '' END 
    ) AS chinesename,
    MAX(
        CASE WHEN wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'price' THEN wp_terms.name ELSE '' END 
    ) AS price
FROM wp_term_relationships, wp_term_taxonomy, wp_terms, wp_posts
WHERE wp_term_relationships.object_id =80
    AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
    AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = wp_terms.term_id
    AND wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_posts.ID
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_title, wp_posts.post_content, wp_posts.post_type
```

Comment: HO MY GOD ... I LOVE YOU even if I don't understand half of what you wrote